# How to display the current_user posst plus the people that user follows?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to display my posts and the people who i'm following as well.
I Tried doing `@posts = Post.where(user_id: current_user.following_users.ids)` and it only shows the posts of the people i follow. What would be the best way to show my posts in the feed?

`UsersController`

```
def following
 @user = User.find params[:id]
 current_user.mark_as_following @user
 redirect_to @user
end
```

`HomeController`

```
def show
 @posts = Post.where(user_id: current_user.following_users.ids)
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could solve it by just adding the current user id to the scope like this

```
def show
  @posts = Post.where(user_id: current_user.following_users.ids + [current_user.id])
end
```